# How to redirect to new domain without parameters

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, parameters

I'm currently trying to redirect an old domain to a new one, but I'm having a small issue. I want to do just 1 single 301 redirect without the parameters...

Right now I have this -> olddomain.com/?dmdald -> newdomain.com/?dmdald -> newdomain.com

So basically I am forced to use two 301 redirects because the parameters remain. Is there any way I can do this below? I'm using wordpress.

olddomain.com/?dmdald -> newdomain.com

I have used the code below and it ultimately works at getting to the end result, but unfortunately it is still using two redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.*
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=.*
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrite in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```